# Имеется Swipe Views with Tabs состоит из 3 фрагментов. Не могу вставить GoogleMap в фрагмент.

Tags: android, google-maps-api

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;

public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {

SupportMapFragment mapFragment;
  GoogleMap map;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1,
            container, false);

    mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map); 
    map = mapFragment.getMap();
    if (map == null) {
      finish();  }

    return rootView;

}  
}

1 ошибка - The method getSupportFragmentManager() is undefined for the type Fragment1   
Fragment1.java  /Reea/src/com/skaaaa    line 25 Java Problem
2 ошибка The method finish() is undefined for the type Fragment1    Fragment1.java  
/Reea/src/com/skaaaa    line 29 Java Problem
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `getFragmentManager()`
2. `getActivity().finish()`

Answer (score 0):

для того чтоб был доступен getSupportFragmentManager() фрагмент должен запускаться из activity унаследованной от FragmentActivity и SupportFragmentManager есть не у фрагмента, а у активити

```
getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
```

Comment: Достаточно вызвать `getFragmentManager()` из фрагмента, что приведёт в точности к такому же результату.